# Gradle kotlin-spring plugin don't open spring classes

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have following gradle script:

```
buildscript {

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${KOTLIN_VERSION}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${KOTLIN_VERSION}")
    }
}

apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper
apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.allopen.gradle.SpringGradleSubplugin
apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin[code]
```

It purpose it to serve as base build for all kotlin based services. Here is how I am applying it:

```
apply from: '../../xxx/xxx.gradle'
```

Then in this project when I have applied generic build template I have something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class MainClass
```

If I remove open it complains that this class shouldn't be final. I would assume that if I use kotlin-spring I don't need to add manually open. I checked this setup against working one from spring initializr and I can't spot the difference. Here is working version

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.1.4-3'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

I can't spot the difference here. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Where you able to solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
apply {
  plugin("kotlin")
  plugin("kotlin-spring")
  plugin("org.springframework.boot")
}
```

https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-kotlin/blob/master/build.gradle.kts